# c# XML read value

Tags: c#, xml

Can anyone tell me how to read the value 500 from the xml document, please?

```
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument(); 

xmldoc.LoadXml ("<move action='bet' value='500' />");
```

Comment: You need to clarify that question. Where is 500?

Comment: If you're talking about querying XML, try this: http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/XML-LINQ/useLinqtoqueryanXMLdocument.htm

Comment: please also post your xml here.

Comment: Sorry, the xml wasn't shown here somehow. I had to add a space before"move"

Comment: If you post code or XML, you need to highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight them

Answer (score 2):

try something like following.

```
string xmlAttributeValue = xmldoc.ChildNodes[0].Attributes["value"].Value
```

Comment: always welcome. :)  and please consider marking this question as answered. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could get try this

```
string attVal = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("move")[0].Attributes["value"].Value
```

Answer (score 1):

This could work too:

```
//Select the node with action='bet'
XmlNode node = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("/move[@action='bet']");
// Read the value of the Attribute 'value'
var value = node.Attributes["value"].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

LINQ to XML http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoXML5MinuteOverview.ashx